# Программа на си. У меня не получается правильно перевести с двоичной системы в "восмиричную"

Tags: c

Знаю что ужасно, из-за этого и прошу помощи. 2 дня уже потратил. :(

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    long int n, i, delitel, posl = 0;
    long int counter = 1, timeless;
    long int number, decimal = 0;
    scanf_s("%d %d %d", &delitel, &n, &number);
    if (delitel == 4) {
        while (number)
        {
            timeless = number % 10 * counter;
            decimal = decimal + timeless;
            number = number / 10;
            counter *= 2;
        }
        while (decimal) {
            posl = 10 * posl + decimal % 4;
            decimal = decimal / 4;
        }
        while (posl) {
            printf("%d", posl % 10);
            posl = posl / 10;
        }
    }
    else if (delitel == 8) {
        while (number)
        {
            timeless = number % 10 * counter;
            decimal = decimal + timeless;
            number = number / 10;
            counter *= 2;
        }
        while (decimal) {
            posl = 10 * posl + decimal % 8;
            decimal = decimal / 8;
        }
        while (posl) {
            printf("%d", posl % 10);
            posl = posl / 10;
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```

[image: задание]

Comment: Давайте вы точно сформулируете задачу. Перевести в восьмеричную систему - как именно? просто получить строковое представление для вывода на экран, или чтобы десятичное число **выглядело так, как** восьмеричное, или что?

Comment: (ЭТО про 4-ричную систему.)Проблема в то, что в vs19 выдает правильный ответ. Как например на сайте моего училища, ответ совсем другой. Может я что-то не понимаю?

Comment: В C++ есть манипляторы для этого. В Си нужно писать код. В принципе не сложно, то же что и на бумажке, только немножко фантазии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Блин.... Просто берете из строки по 2 (для системы 4) или 3 (для 8) цифры и переводите из в нужную цифру. Всё! Как вы вообще собирались загонять 1000 цифр в `int`?...

Всегда, **всегда**, **ВСЕГДА** давайте полное условие, а не начинайте выяснять, какой рукой держать микроскоп при забивании гвоздей...

```
int main()
{
    int d, L;
    scanf("%d %d\n",&d,&L);
    char s[1005];
    scanf("%s",s);
    printf("[%s]\n",s);
    d = (d==4)?2:3;
    char * c = s;
    for(int i = 0; i < L/d; ++i)
    {
        int x = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < d; ++j)
            x = x*2+ *c++ -'0';
        printf("%d",x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Может я что-то не так понял. Но ведь можно сразу делить и делать вывод в цикле. (не бейте)

Comment: Что вы собираетесь делить? 1000-значное число? Вы понимаете, что ваша программа в общем случае просто не считывает все переданные ей данные?

Comment: я понимаю, мне хотелось в начале сделать через массив. Но потом решил хотя бы так. Проверить. Будет ли работать.

Comment: "Хотя бы так" - не будет. Ну интереса ради задайте 20-значное число. Вот вам входные данные - `4 22 1010101010101010101011` Правильный ответ - `22222222223`. Можете пробовать...

Comment: Спасибо вам. Но если не сложно. Можете объяснить принцип программы? Я понимаю что связано со сдвигом. Но не понимаю суть.

Comment: Ну 4 - это 2 бита, 8 - три. Преобразовываем, как у вас - только делим не на 10, а на 4 - а в двоичной 4 - это 100. Вот и получается - остаток - по 2 знака. Для восьмеричной 8 - это 1000, каждые 3 бита дают одну восьмеричную цифру...

Comment: хм... слишком сложно для моего мозга. Если вас не затруднит. Не могли бы вы скинуть ссылку где можно прочитать об этом.(можно даже в англоязычном варианте.)

Comment: а все, понял о чем вы

Comment: Ну, если все понятно и ответ устроил - его можно принять (птичка слева от ответа).

Comment: Если L не кратно 3 (или 2 для 4-х ричной системы), то надо добавить ноликов в старшую цифру в двоичной записи

Comment: @avp См. на картинке с исходным условием - "гарантируется, что L кратно 2, если A = 4, и кратно 3, если A =8"...

Comment: @Harry, ну, если гарантируется ... ("Стопроцентную гарантию даёт только страховой полис" -- О. Бендер)

Comment: @avp И вы Бендера перевираете... :( Не гарантию, а спокойствие. "У самого выхода Полыхаев схватил Остапа за рукав и пролепетал:

— Я ничего не утаил. Честное слово! Я могу быть спокоен? Правда?

— Полное спокойствие может дать человеку только страховой полис, — ответил Остап, не замедляя хода. — Так вам скажет любой агент по страхованию жизни. "

Comment: @Harry, да, уж ... похоже пора.  Придётся переквалифицироваться в управдомы.